# Clustering with Scipy in Python? (hierarchical clustering)

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, hierarchical-clustering

I'm a bit confused about the clusering with Scipy in Python. Here is my sourcecode:

```
import scipy.spatial.distance as dist
import numpy, scipy

dataMatrix = numpy.array(matrix)
distMatrix = dist.pdist(dataMatrix, 'euclidean')
distSquareMatrix = dist.squareform(distMatrix)

Y = scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage(distSquareMatrix, method='complete')
```

Do I have to use the 'distMatrix' or the squareform 'distSquareMatrix' as input for the clustering? Because I saw both methods in other posts. But the output is different. Now I'm not sure what I have to choose.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the distance matrix in condensed form without transforming it with `squareform`. The `squareform` function is useful if you want to manipulate the distance matrix yourself more easily as a 2D array. The `scipy.cluster.hierarchy` functions use the condensed form for the purpose of saving roughly a factor of two in memory.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That means I have to use 'distMatrix' in the linkage function...